# Codeigniter Botdetect/Tank-Auth Captcha 404 Not found on Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, codeigniter-3, tankauth

I want to use Tank auth in my CodeIgniter project, but there is need to start with basic installation of Botdetect captcha in CodeIgniter.

I have followed the Quickstart Installation guide on this [link](https://captcha.com/php-captcha.html#php-codeigniter-crashcourse).

The view upon which I am trying to run this provision is saved under application/views/welcome_message.php, which is here below:

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="<?php echo CaptchaUrls::LayoutStylesheetUrl() ?>" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php echo $captchaHtml; ?>
        <input type="text" name="CaptchaCode" id="CaptchaCode" value="" />
    </body>
</html>
```

And the corresponding Controller is saved under application/controllers/Welcome.php, also here below:

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index() // Your controller
    {
        // load the BotDetect Captcha library and set its parameter
        $this->load->library('botdetect/BotDetectCaptcha', array(
            'captchaConfig' => 'ExampleCaptcha'
        ));

        // make Captcha Html accessible to View code
        $data['captchaHtml'] = $this->botdetectcaptcha->Html();
        $this->load->view('welcome_message',$data);
    }
}
```

When run on my browser this is what I received:

[image: Captcha Page]

I understand the BotDetect is using session and I have managed to fix the required configurations and sessions are being created in "ci_sessions" on each run.

How can I solve this problem to load BotDetect Captcha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to register BotDetect Captcha route used for BotDetect Captcha requests (Captcha images, sounds, resources, etc.) in "application/config/routes.php" file.

Please check the following 2 points:

1 - make sure that you have registered BotDetect Captcha route in your "routes.php" file

```
$route['botdetect/captcha-handler'] = 'botdetect/captcha_handler/index';
```

2 - in your "controllers" folder needs to have "/controllers/botdetect/Captcha_handler.php" file

I hope this helps.